# Doctrine - Search in multiple tables returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a search query using Doctrine DQL. I have to search in multiple tables by a giver criteria.

The problem is, it returns nothing. Knowing that there's rows that match the criteria.

Here's my query:

```
public function getResults($query)
{
    $q = $this->em->createQuery(
        "
            select u, pr, t, ex
            from Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\User u,
                 Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\Product pr,
                 Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\Tip t,
                 Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\Experience ex
            where u.firstname like :crit
            or pr.name like :crit
            or t.title like :crit
            or ex.title like :crit
        "
    );
    $q->setParameter("crit", "%" .  strtolower($query) . "%");
    return $q->execute();
}
```

Here's my controller action:

```
public function postSearchAction(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->query->get("q");
    $result = $this->get("zgh_fe.search_manager")->getResults($query);
    var_dump($query);
    var_dump($result);
    die;
}
```

**NOTE** When I remove the last two tables from the query it returns results.

```
public function getResults($query)
{
    $q = $this->em->createQuery(
        "
            select u, pr
            from Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\User u,
                 Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\Product pr,
            where u.firstname like :crit
            or pr.name like :crit
        "
    );
    $q->setParameter("crit", "%" .  strtolower($query) . "%");
    return $q->execute();
}
```

Resulting SQL query: https://gist.github.com/rafaeladel/2f37748a732c9393a07f

Comment: `SELECT` from multiple tables is the same as statement with `INNER JOIN`. Possibly you are looking for `LEFT JOIN` instead?

Comment: @VisioN Hmmm, So how to perform a left join when there's no parent table to join with ? (The tables are separated)

Comment: Check your profiler regarding the real SQL query. Most probably it will display something like `SELECT ... FROM users INNER JOIN products ON users.id = products.users_id INNER JOIN tips ON ...`.

Comment: @VisioN I can't find any inner joins in it, I've edited the question with the resulting SQL query.

Comment: I assume these tables are related to each other, aren't they?

Comment: @VisioN Well, users table has a relation to all of the other tables. Since user may have product, tip or experience.

Comment: Then most probably all other tables are `INNER JOIN`'ed to the 'users' table. If you set 'users' table as the main and to the `LEFT JOIN` it will probably fetch all data by all related tables.

Comment: @VisioN Hmmm, So I will have to select by the users table. I can't select by those tables separately without `join` by any way ?

Comment: The idea behind ORM is returning an object which represents a row in a table where properties act like table columns or columns of other joined tables. If you try to select objects from multiple separate tables, you need to use separate queries, which will map all rows of each table to own objects. Selecting multiple different unrelated objects using one single query is not possible with Doctrine. This is one of the reasons why Doctrine doesn't support UNION, since it contradicts the basic idea.

Comment: @VisioN Ah I get it. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I've used `left join` and it's working now. Thanks.